# SQL sum results of one table and join tables

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to list the project name and the total hours per week (by all employees) on that project, for each project. The report must have the project name and the total hrs. The total hours column should read total hrs worked and the project name column should read project name

For some reason my code is showing one of the wrong columns: I need it to show the total hours instead of the PRODUCT NUMBER

Here is my code:

```
SELECT pname AS [PRODUCT NAME], pnumber AS [PRODUCT NUMBER]
FROM project as a
JOIN
( 
SELECT PNO, SUM(HOURS) TOTALHOURS
FROM WORKS_ON
    GROUP BY PNO
) as b
on a.pnumber = B.PNO
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the tag you are not using either `mysql` or `sql-server` as both are different.

Comment: @M57 . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using problem join condition and grouping as shown below

```
SELECT pname AS [PRODUCT NAME], 
       pnumber AS [PRODUCT NUMBER],
       SUM(HOURS) TOTALHOURS
FROM project as a
INNER JOIN  WORKS_ON w ON w.Pno = a.pnumber
    GROUP BY a.pname,a.pnumber
```